# thick line in array environment

Tags: arrays, line

I am using an array environment, not tabular, which makes it impossible to use such commands as

```
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}

\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}

\noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
```

for making line thicker. I have solved the problem with the vertical lines by using the command

```
\newcolumntype{"}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 1pt\hskip\tabcolsep}}
```

and with the horizontal lines by using

```
\Xhline{1pt}
```

Is this correct or is there a better way?
I thank you very much

Carlo Alberto

Comment: `array` and `tabular` are the same code apart from the fact that array cells are in math mode, why do you say your tabular version is impossible?

Comment: I did not add the boldline package. Now I will use one (or more) of the suggested commands (the tip on the colored line is also very useful). Thanks

Answer (score 10):

They all work within the `array` environment. Here is a demo with `makecell`, `boldline` and `booktabs`. `\cmidrule` can even be used in the `xmatrix` environments:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array, boldline, makecell, booktabs, amsmath}
    \newcommand\btrule[1]{\specialrule{#1}{0pt}{0pt}}
    \usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}

    \begin{document}

  \[ \begin{array}{l!{\vline width 1pt}c | r }
      \arrayrulecolor{IndianRed} \Xhline{1pt}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      \hline
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
      \hline
      7 & 8 & 9 \\
      \Xhline{1pt}
    \end{array}
    \qquad
    \begin{array}{ lV{2.5}c | r }
      \hlineB{2.5}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      \hline
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
      \hline
      7 & 8 & 9 \\
      \hlineB{2.5}
    \end{array}
    \qquad
    \begin{array}{ l!{\color{IndianRed}\vline width 1pt}c | r }
      \arrayrulecolor{IndianRed}
      \btrule{1pt}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      \arrayrulecolor{black} \hline
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
      \hline
      7 & 8 & 9 \\
      \arrayrulecolor{IndianRed}\btrule{1pt}
    \end{array}
    \qquad
    \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
       \cmidrule(lr){1-3}
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
       \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
      7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \noalign{\setlength{\aboverulesep{-2ex}}
    \arrayrulecolor{IndianRed}\cmidrule(lr){1-3}
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thank you very much. Excellent and very helpful answer. They all work indeed

Answer (score 2):

For information, you can also draw thick rules (or whatever rule you want) in an array with the environment `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`. This environment is similar to the environment `{array}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. You can use Tikz to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz after the construction of the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 10 & 14 & 15 \\
0 & 2 & 10 & 14 & 15 \\
0 & 0 & 10 & 14 & 15 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\CodeAfter 
  \tikz \draw [thick] (2-|1) -- (2-|2) |- (3-|3) |- (4-|6) ;
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]